# How to match uiimage orientation to text in the image

Tags: ios, swift, image-rotation, ciimage, text-recognition

After taking a photo of a document, I use `CIDetector` to auto crop the image, this works fine. But the image is rarely correctly oriented when I want to display it in a uiimageview. I know how to rotate it manually, but I want to be able to recognize the correct orientation based on the text in the document, so that the user never has to do anything.

I tried looping through every possible orientation, using `CIDetector` to detect possible areas containing text in a loop, but that doesn't give a definitive answer. Also tried TesseractOCR with disappointing results.

Any other suggestions?